# Transference principle

Tags: logic, order-theory, model-theory

How can I proof this:

Show that if $\sigma$ is a $\forall\exists-$sentence in the language $\mathcal{L} = \{<\}$ which is true for all finite linear orders then $\sigma$ is true in **any** lineal order.

I have tried to use the union of elemental chains but I am not sure if lineal orders is the crecent union of finite lineal orders. I also tried to use the transference principle from $\forall$ to $\exists$ and viceversa but I do not get to any place

Answer (score 4):

Let $L$ be a linear order and let $\forall \bar{x} \exists \bar{y} \phi(\bar{x}, \bar{y})$ be an $\forall \exists$-sentence that is true in every finite linear order (so $\phi(\bar{x}, \bar{y})$ is quantifier-free). Now let $\bar{a}$ be an arbitrary tuple in $L$, matching the length of $\bar{x}$. We write $A$ for the substructure of $L$ with universe $\bar{a}$. So $A$ is a finite linear order. By assumption we have that $A \models \forall \bar{x} \exists \bar{y} \phi(\bar{x}, \bar{y})$, so in particular $A \models \exists \bar{y} \phi(\bar{a}, \bar{y})$. Since $\exists \bar{y} \phi(\bar{a}, \bar{y})$ is an $\exists$-formula (with parameters from $A$) it is preserved upwards by the substructure relation, so we conclude that $L \models \exists \bar{y} \phi(\bar{a}, \bar{y})$. As $\bar{a}$ was arbitrary we thus have $L \models \forall \bar{x} \exists \bar{y} \phi(\bar{x}, \bar{y})$, as required.

Comment: Thanks! It was very helpful Can you explain one thing of your answer "We write $A$ for the substructure of $L$ with universe \overline{a}"?

Comment: So $\bar{a}$ is a tuple, say $\bar{a} = (a_1, \ldots, a_n)$. Then we can form a substructure $A = \{a_1, \ldots, a_n\} \subseteq L$. So that means that we use the elements from $\bar{a}$ to form the universe of the structure $A$ and that the relation symbol $<$ is inherited from $L$. It is then an easy check that $A$ is indeed a linear order.

Comment: Can you prove this by arguing that every linear order is a limit of finite linear orders?

Comment: @Asaf But what guarantee do we have that $A$ is in that limit :p ? Or did you mean the entire statement?

Comment: (1) The entire statement; (2) obviously the point is that a linear order is the limit of *all* of its finite subsets (as a directed system, not as a sequence, since that's impossible for uncountable orders, although using LS it is enough to prove the transfer principle for countable linear orders).

Comment: @Asaf Ah right, I wasn't sure how serious your question was. So yes, you could, but it is overkill and really the argument boils down to the above. Roughly: pick finitely many elements in the big structure, find some structure in your limit diagram containing them, have something be true there and push that truth to the big structure.

Comment: @MarkKamsma Thank you! I finally understand this proof Congrats!

Comment: An overkill would be proving this for linear orders below the least supercompact and then use a Laver diamond to argue it for all linear orders.